# How to resize and add images in mongo DB with mongoose in node js from client side and also be able to view the images in ejs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to resize the image and upload it to Mongo DB is it possible to do it in node and express with mongoose and please add an explanation of the code too. It would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally did with multer, gridfs and jimp(main packages)

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const multer = require('multer');
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const crypto = require("crypto")
const Jimp = require("jimp")

const app = express();

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static("public"));

// Mongo URI
const mongoURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/newDB';

// Create mongo connection
//useUnifiedTopology will not work with mongoose.createConnection
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI , { useUnifiedTopology: true ,useNewUrlParser: true });

// Init gfs
let gfs;

conn.once('open', () => {
  // Init stream
  gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('uploads');
});

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/newDB", { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true })

const imageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    image: String,
    User: String,
    forTest: String
  });

  const Image = mongoose.model('image', imageSchema);


// Create storage engine
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,
  file: (req, file) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: 'uploads'
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Image.find({}, function(err, files)  {
    // Check if files
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      res.render('index', { fileSent: false });
    } else {
      res.render('index', { fileSent: files });
    }
  });
});

app.post('/upload', upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {

if(req.file === undefined || req.file === 0 || req.file === ""){
  res.redirect("/");
}

if(req.file.contentType === "image/png" || req.file.contentType === "image/jpg" || req.file.contentType === "image/jpeg"){

Jimp.read("http://localhost:3000/image/" + req.file.filename, (err, image) => {
  if (err) {
    // on every error render the error page with error message and type
    console.log(err);
  }

  image
    .resize(550, Jimp.AUTO)
      image.getBase64(Jimp.AUTO, (error1, base64Image) => {
        if(error1){
          console.log(error1);
        }
        const image1 = new Image({
          image: base64Image,
          User: "Avichal",
          forTest: "Hindi1"
        })

        image1.save(function(error){
          if(error){
            console.log(error);
          }
           })
    })
    gfs.remove({ _id: req.file.id, root: 'uploads' }, (err, gridStore) => {
      if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      }
       res.redirect('/');
    });
})

}else{
  gfs.remove({ _id: req.file.id, root: 'uploads' }, (err, gridStore) => {
    if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    }
     res.redirect('/');
  });
}
});

app.get('/:filename', (req, res) => {
  Image.findOne({ image: req.params.filename }, (err, file) => {
    // Check if the input is a valid image or not
    if (!file || file.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: 'No file exists'
      });
    }
    // If the file exists then it is an image
      // Read output to browser
      const readstream = Image.createReadStream(file.image);
      readstream.pipe(res);

  });
});

//for reading the multer image(it is important as first read the multer image with jimp read and then resize it and then delete the multer image)
app.get('/:image/:filename', (req, res) => {
  if(req.params.image === "image"){
  gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename }, (err, file) => {
    // Check if the input is a valid image or not
    if (!file || file.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: 'No file exists'
      });
    }

    // If the file exists then check whether it is an image
    if (file.contentType === 'image/jpeg' || file.contentType === 'image/png') {
      // Read output to browser
      const readstream = gfs.createReadStream(file.filename);
      readstream.pipe(res);
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({
        err: 'Not an image'
      });
    }
  });
}
});

app.delete('/files/:id', (req, res) => {

    Image.deleteOne({_id: req.params.id}, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
res.redirect("/")
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server started on port 3000"));
```